# Tradingview chart in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, webview, desktop, tradingview-api

I want to use TradingView's webView in flutter desktop project. But unfortunately webView not support in desktop version.
Is there any way to use webView in app?

Comment: I think "trading_chart: ^0.1.2" this package working in web

Comment: Yes it's works. But I want show a tradingView website in a flutter desktop app

Comment: Have you tried webview_windows: ^0.1.6 ?

Comment: It's just for Windows not all platforms

Comment: Well use multiple packages and check if the device is windows use this package.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar just try this `https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts` package

Comment: syncfusion_flutter_charts Not good for me. But Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately just there is a package for Windows. There is no packages for Linux and macOS.

Comment: can you please share your code? I want do the same but I don't need it for windows

Comment: I didn't use webView. Just use a chart package.